# How do i get data from one "View" into another "View" using MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

That is the basic question. I have looked through a bunch of posts on SO and im not finding quite what im looking for.

Very simple, **if I am on Index.aspx with data vars populated in my javascript, how do I call an action in my controller and load a new page where i can populate the vars i sent from the index page?**

I currently have solutions that get me most of the way there but not all the way. I am new to MVC so i am probably over complicating something that is simple and then looking in the wrong places for an answer ... Please Help

The only way i have managed to get this to work so far is by doing an ajax post request sending the data variables i need from `Page 1` , Setting the `Session Variable` then in the ajax.success section on page 1 I redirect to page 2 using `window.location.href = "~MyUrl~"`

This works .... but there has to be a better way of doing it ...

Comment: Why don't you show your current attempt at solving the problem and describe the issues it, specifically.

Comment: original post updated

Comment: Is the purpose of the ajax call to validate the data so you don't redirect with invalid data? Otherwise you could probably just use the form to post directly to the other page you're looking to call later.

Comment: If you are using it for validation, instead of using window.location.href you could simply sumbit your form instead and have it point to the page that holds your view. That way the ajax call validates the data and upon success calls the other controller method.